# Can you name this 386/486 era computer case?

Tags: ibm-pc, case, multimedia

Escort Computer is a Local PC brand in Turkey. They had popular Escort Multimedia series in late 90's. Prominent with distinctive case design. They were using off the shelf OEM hardware. I believe, the case must not be a exception. Probably supplied from a far east manufacturer. Can you name this case or the manufacturer?

[image]

Escort Multimedia 486 Case (Soundblaster Live accessory was added later.)

[image: Escort Multimedia 386 Magazine Advert]

Escort Multimedia 386 Magazine Advert

Comment: Do you have an example in your possession? Have you searched it carefully for markings?

Comment: There were a variety of oddball case formats sold over the years, I think hoping that the design would stand out. But most people either didn't really care, or wanted the case to be boring and not stand out.

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't personally have. I have learnt ASI brand was using pretty smiliar case circa 1995.

Comment: One of an endless number of Taiwan creations fuelling he home/shop build market. they never really had recognizeable brand names as those companies as well had a high fluctuation.

Answer (score 7):

I have this model, it's PC Palladium MultiMedia - MMTV486DX2-66. As far as I know this was sold in Germany, but I couldn't find much on the company or the model itself (no adverts etc.) It's visibly different than the Escord model you shown on the other picture and the advert poster.

It's really unique looking PC case! Here's mine (pardon the gaping holes where the drives should be, still waiting for these to arrive):

[image]